# Beatiful Soup Extract Information

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract the name of the chemical, its occurrences/uses and date added by using beautiful soup. 
This is the one example of the chemical in the list
https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/abiraterone-acetate

Can anyone help me with it? thank you very much!

my desire output will be

```
Abiraterone acetat from L253
<h1 class="title" id="page-title"><span class="ca-gov-icon-arrow-down"></span> Abiraterone acetate </h1>

A CYP17 inhibitor indicated in combination with prednisone for the treatment of patients with metastatic castration-resistant prostate cancer
from L265
<h3 class="label-above">Occurence(s)/Use(s)</h3><p>A CYP17 inhibitor indicated in combination with prednisone for the treatment of patients with metastatic castration-resistant prostate cancer.</p>

02/02/2016 from L266
<h3 class="label-above">Date Added</h3><span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2016-02-02T00:00:00-08:00">02/02/2016</span>  </div>
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried to extract the name of the chemical?

Comment: temp = str(soup.find_all('p')) I have used this to find the occurrences of the chemical. however the occurances does not show up

Comment: @RunyaoYin be informed that you dealing with `Incapsula` firewall which will block any try to parse the site content

Comment: @RunyaoYin check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note that the website is protected with `incapsula` firewall to prevent robots and browser automation.

Using `Selenium` we can achieve your target below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/abiraterone-acetate'
sada = browser.get(url)
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'title'})
print(title.text.strip())
details = soup.find(string='Occurence(s)/Use(s)').find_next('p').contents[0]
print(details)
date = soup.find('span', {'class': 'date-display-single'})
print(date.text)

browser.close()
```

Output:

```
Abiraterone acetate
A CYP17 inhibitor indicated in combination with prednisone for the treatment of patients with metastatic castration-resistant prostate cancer.
02/02/2016
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help here. I have tried your code and i get an error message: Not a directory: 'geckodriver'

Comment: @RunyaoYin you need to install the driver ! [click here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/docs/source/index.rst#drivers)

Comment: Hi, what should I do after I download the driver. How can I execute it on Mac?

Comment: @RunyaoYin well so you have downloaded `Safari` driver ? correct? so place it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I actually cannot find where to download the driver for Safari based on the website you share

Comment: @RunyaoYin if you are using `homebrew` so run the following cmd `brew install selenium-server-standalone`

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded it

Comment: @RunyaoYin you welcome, you can accept my question by selecting ✔ mark beside the question.

Comment: Hi, I run into a problem again when I'm trying to put your code into an interaction to go through a list of chemicals. It seems that it keeps accessing the first website only

Comment: @RunyaoYin are you looping over a lit of urls ?

Comment: Hi, I resolve the issue that I just mentioned. But I just noticed that for some of the chemicals, there are more than one date of listing. Can you help me with extracting all listing dates and note their reason for listing (e.g. cancer, reproductive). Thank you very much!